# how to get getUTCDate() with 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to get getUTCDate() and getUTCMonth() with 0 ?

my code is

```
var d = new Date();
        var day = d.getUTCDate();
        var month = d.getUTCMonth()+1;
        var year = d.getUTCFullYear();
```

If  Today date is 1-1-2015 than i want to `day=01 instead of  1` and `month=01 instead of 1`;

Comment: The value is an integer... you're talking about a *string* representation of the integer. But if you're formatting the date, you shouldn't be doing that manually anyway... use the built-in formatting facilities or a library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in shortcut for doing that. You just put a `0` in front of it if necessary:

```
var month = String(d.getUTCMonth());
if (month.length === 1) {
    month = "0" + month;
}
```

Or use a date/time library like MomentJS which features formatting functions.

On modern browsers, you can also dice up the string `toISOString` gives you, as it's always in UTC:

```
var parts = d.toISOString().substring(0, 10).split("-");
var day = parts[2];
var month = parts[1];
var year = parts[0];
```